# Java Swing and JGoodies

Tags: java, swing, jgoodies

I developing a simple desktop system in Java

My system will have a database that is connected to a front end.

Now I want to use JGoodies for the design of the user interface.

Is JGoodies an extension of the Swing GUI framework?

Do I have to master the Java Swing GUI framework before I can learn to use JGoodies?

Or can I learn JGooodies without first mastering the Java Swing GUI framework?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You definitely need to learn Swing to use JGoodies. JGoodies provides additional look and feels, layouts, Swing components and helper classes, but the UI framework is still Swing.